# Access TextView from CardView Adapter into RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

This question is similar to [Accessing items in CardView after it has been created and put into a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512561/accessing-items-in-cardview-after-it-has-been-created-and-put-into-a-recyclervie). But I didn't understand the answer.

I have a `CardViewAdapter ViewHolder` -

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView card_text;
    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        card_text = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
    }
}
```

And I access it using `OnBindViewHolder` which is in the same, `CardViewAdapter` -

```
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.card_text.setText(mColorData[position]);
        viewHolder.card_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
}
```

But I also have a `RecyclerView` and now I wish to access the `TextView` from this `CardViewAdapter` and use it in my `RecyclerView` Activity so that I can set an action when it is (long) clicked.

My `RecyclerView` -

```
public class RecyclerViewMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        String[] colorData = {
        //a simple string array
        }

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new CardViewDataMainAdapter(colorData);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                //do stuff here
       }

      @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                //I want to do stuff here using TextView from CardViewAdapter.
       }
   }
```

P.S. I've implemented `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` using https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826692/4458075

Comment: Where is your recyclerview code??

Comment: In my latest edit :)

Comment: Your RecyclerView is different activity and the textview you are asking about having multiple instances in cardview adapter

Comment: Exactly. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: There are mutiple textview, how would you know which textview you have to use??? And why do you exactly needed the textview??? What you can do is make a json array and stored it in file and use that json array file in recycler view

Comment: I'm really new to Recyclerview and Adapters and android programming overall.
Apparently I have no idea how to use json files (but i'll definitely look for it now).
And about textview, no, there's just a single textview but multiple "positions".

Comment: Same textview at multiple position means its obvious that it will have different value at different position.